# MIDI revisited 19.10 Rhythmbox

Tags: 19.10, rhythmbox, midi

I'd like to be able to play MIDI files through one of the default Ubuntu media players, preferably Rhythmbox. For some reason, clicking on a MIDI file in file manager launches "Videos". MIDI files are not video. Nevertheless, the MIDI file does not play and I am told to download a MIDI decoder. So I click on the button that says "Find in Ubuntu Software". This then opens the Ubuntu Software application which immediately greets me with a grey SAD FACE icon and no decoder is found. Well done.

How can I get Rhythmbox to play MIDI files? It is a multimedia audio player, no?

Comment: You need a software synthesizer like TiMidity or FluidSynth.

Comment: There is no option for those things under Rhythmbox's "Configure Plugins" dialog.

Comment: Okay, so I installed timidity and its associated packages for Ubuntu 19.10 and... now I have no sound at all. Audio is set to "dummy output" in Settings and there is no other option to choose. Timidity won't play MIDI files of course, even though it reads them and displays MIDI information. And there is absolutely no more sound output at all. Great.

Comment: More information. removing timidity and its associated packages restores normal audio. Still no MIDI :-(